# How can I play windows game on linux mint?

Tags: wine, games

I want to play windows game on linux mint ? What version of wine should I use?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. In its current form, your question doesn't give us enough information to help you with your problem. In this particular case, it would be a good start to tell us which game you're trying to play, what you have tried so far, and what hasn't been working as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can guarantee that a specific program or game will work but the only way to know for sure is to try it.

As to the question on version, there is absolutely no reason to use any other version than the latest one.

If your game doesn't work in Wine, be aware that there are other solutions like Qemu and other VM systems that would allow you to install Windows over Linux, but the best way to run software, especially a game, is by running the proper OS.

Some people who wish to stick to certain applications on both systems prefer installing both with a dual boot.